# Firebase screen name is showing not set

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I have created a project in `Google Firebase Analytics` and I am able to log screen names in the console. But for one screen `screen_view` is not recorded and it is showing as **not set** in the screen view list. I have used a default function for logging screen view event (i.e. setCurrentScreen()).

I am using `Firebase:16.0.0` version. Can anyone please guide me for this.

[image: Firebase Issue]

Answer (score 8):

put

```
analytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "Screen Name", this.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

in `onResume()`.

Comment: setCurrentScreen is deprecated, any suggestions? I am unable to see the screen name.

Answer (score 4):

Debug it in real-time with logcat to figure out why it's not properly set. My best guess is that you're trying to call `setCurrentScreen()` while passing an activity that's not in the proper state.

Possible solution: move logging to `onResume()`.

Comment: You are right I used `setCurrentScreen()` I debugged it and it is showing event is sent. I can see the `class name` of the screen but I am not able to see `Screen name` in `Screen name` tab.

Comment: Is it the automatic screen tracking or your own manual that is logged? Watch for "W/FA: setCurrentScreen cannot be called while no activity active". Possible solution in edited answer.