# Why Firebase shows not set for screen_name

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am sending screen views to firebase by calling setCurrentScreen(activity, screenname, classname) for some screen. but on dashboard why it showed not set for screen_name?

[screen shot of dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgsQo.png)

Comment: Your code is probably not actually setting the value.  Please edit the question to show the code.  Make sure you explain the values of any variables in use.

Comment: @DougStevenson Screen names are there for which screen i used that setCurrentScreen method like "Home" as seen in screenshot. but my question is why the value not set is there?

Comment: If the Firebase console isn't working the way you expect, please contact Firebase support directly for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952080/firebase-screen-name-is-showing-not-set/