# Not able to track screen name in Firebase Analytics: Screen name (not set)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using the following block of code to track screens and user events in my application, but screen name.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_corporate);

    FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Corporate Screen - Android");
    mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "Corporate Screen Android", null);
    mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("Corporate_Screen_Android", params);

    initViews();
}
```

[image: Firebase Console]

Comment: Duplicate (with solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952080/firebase-screen-name-is-showing-not-set/

Comment: @Vesper There is nothing as such mention in the firebase documentation of Firebase Analytics, So why I need to declare it into the onResume method.

Comment: I have set Screen Name in OnResume() itself, still the Firebase shows me NOT_SET with some percentage? Is there any other reason to categorize as NOT_SET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place the following code:

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "Screen Name", null);
```

in `onResume()` method of Activity.

Comment: setCurrentScreen is deprecated and I see not set for screen_name, screen_view on analytics.google.com. Any advise?